# Materialized Path to HTML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I tried converting a materialized path to HTML in PHP. This is my data structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 7
            [name] => Parent 1
            [parent] => 
            [deep] => 
            [lineage] => 00007
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 9
            [name] => Child of Parent 1
            [parent] => 7
            [deep] => 1
            [lineage] => 00007-00009
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 12
            [name] => Child of Child 1
            [parent] => 9
            [deep] => 2
            [lineage] => 00007-00009-00012
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 10
            [name] => Parent 2
            [parent] => 
            [deep] => 
            [lineage] => 00010
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 11
            [name] => Child of Parent 2
            [parent] => 10
            [deep] => 1
            [lineage] => 00010-00011
        )

)
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li >
     <a href="#">Parent</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Child</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
foreach ($list as $node) {
   $element = $doc->createElement('li', $node['name_de']);
   $parent = $doc->appendChild($element);
}
echo ($doc->saveHTML());
```

Is what I want to achieve even possible without recursion? My code unfortunately adds everything as parent...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, you need recursion. The recursion is not the problem anyway, but that you would iterate the items to often. So to avoid this you need to store the data in a way that you can access it by id:

```
$items = [];
$index = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
  $items[$item['product_id']] = $item;
  $index[$item['parent']][] = $item['product_id'];
}
```

`$items` provides the items by `product_id`. `$index` allows to get the children of an item.

Now a function can append the item, check if here are child items, append the `ul` and call itself for each child item.

```
function appendItem(\DOMNode $parentNode, $itemId, array $items, array $index) {
  $dom = $parentNode->ownerDocument;
  if ($item = $items[$itemId]) {
    $node = $parentNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('li'));
    $node->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($item['name']));
    if (isset($index[$itemId]) && is_array($index[$itemId])) {
      $list = $node->appendChild($dom->createElement('ul'));
      foreach ($index[$itemId] as $childItemId) {
        appendItem($list, $childItemId, $items, $index);
      }
    }
  }
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$parentNode = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('ul'));
foreach ($index[0] as $itemId) {
  appendItem($parentNode, $itemId, $items, $index);
}

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ul>
  <li>Parent 1<ul><li>Child of Parent 1<ul><li>Child of Child 1</li></ul></li></ul></li>
  <li>Parent 2<ul><li>Child of Parent 2</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just did a minor tweak because it didn't find $index[0] at first. I replaced the line `$index[$item['parent']][] = $item['product_id'];` with `$index[isset($item['parent'])?$item['parent']:0][] = $item['product_id'];` Wirklich super, herzlichen Dank!